# Using python to search for string and do something when another string is present

Tags: python, file

I have a python script that searches through a file:

this is a sample of the input text file:

```
String A 1
String B 1
String B 2
String B 3
String A 2
String B 4
```

It stores a numerical value in string A, then does some processing for each existence of a segment of string B where each segment is a different number

```
y=0
while y < len(InFileStr):
    if "String A" in InFileStr[y]:
        StringA = int(InFileStr[y].split("")[2])
    elif "String B" in InFileStr[y]):
        print "String B" + int(InFileStr[y].split("")[2])"\n"
    y+=1
```

This "should" produce:

```
String B 1
String B 2
String B 3
String B 4
```

where StringA =2 as it's overwritten

However, can't figure out how to just print

```
String B 1
String B 4
```

Comment: Are you missing a increment at the end of that while loop? Regardless, instead of using a while loop, you should probably use `for line in InFileStr`.

Comment: don't understand, what is the expected output?

Comment: sorry left out a y+=1

Comment: The expected output is that we only process String B twice, not 4 times.

Comment: And, presumably, a preceding `y = 0`.  I think we'll need some more clarification of what this is meant to do before we can be much more helpful.

Comment: What if the sequence is A A B B? Process one or both B's?

Comment: Hi Janne, if sequence is A1 A2 B1 B2, we store A2 and use it to process B1, we don't process B2.

Comment: as an aside: this is not about the "Processing" programming language, so don't use that tag in the future (hover over the tag to see its definition)

Comment: I'm still in the dark as to what the OP actually wants to do!  For the given example data, what is the expected output????

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to interpret what you're looking for, it seems like you just wanted to pair the closest A-string, with a B-string.  In which case all you needed was a variable to keep track of the last A string, that way you know you can execute on a B-String.  If this is the case, the below code should hopefully work for you.

```
lastLineStraingA = False

for line in infile.readlines():
    if "StringA" in line:
        lastLineStringA = True
        storeValueInLine(line)
        continue
    elif ("StringB" in line) and (True == lastLineStringA):
        process(line)

    lastLineStringA = False
```

Comment: Excellent man, this works. Apologies to all for the cryptic nature of the question in the first place.

Comment: no problem.  Someone had suggested I edit the post to not have the continue in the if condition.  This was done intentionally to capture and correctly set the lastLine variable in the event that you had a String-C.  I'm updating the (true) to (True).  Since I was in C++ mode :P

Answer (score 0):

see if this will help you

```
while y < len(InFileStr):
    if "String A" in InFileStr[y]:
        flag = True    
        storevalueInLine()
    elif "String B" in InFileStr[y]):
        if flag:
            process(StringB)
            flag = False
    y+=1
```